# How to find an img src from this part of text by php regex?

Tags: regex

I've tried some solutions found in web, but it didn't help.

Given:
`<p><img alt="" src="images/img2.jpg" style="float:left; height:300px; width:600px" /></p><p>bla-bla-bla</p>`

I need to get:
`images/img2.jpg`.

Using now: `preg_match('$<img.*src="(.*)"$', $text, $matches);` and it does not give a result.

Comment: What language? What are these solutions that you tried? Is it possible that the text contains multiple `src` attributes?

Comment: forgot to specify lang :) php.
yeap, its possible. but i need to get only the first img src

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex: `<img.*src="(.*)".*/>`

This will match your image tags and the first capture group will give you your path.  Your specific language may require some massaging of the regex.

In general, parsing tags with regex is not a good idea, however (if your tag spans lines it won't hit it, for instance).

Comment: Need to use a non-greedy quantifier so it doesn't fail on `<img src="foo.gif"/> Blah <img src="bar.gif"/>`. Try `<img.*?src="(.*?)"` The closing tag is unnecessary.

Comment: does not give a result

Comment: You may need to escape the double quotation marks and angled brackets.  I'm not familiar with PHP syntax.  $ in regex generally have a different meaning than the way you're using them in preg_match('$<img.*src="(.*)"$', $text, $matches);

Comment: there is no difference if i use slash instead of $

Comment: http://ca1.php.net/preg_match - I think you want preg_match('/<img.*?src=\"(.*)\"/', $text, $matches); but again, I can't be sure as I'm not in a PHP environment.